# Command orm:generate-entities Error : Class not found when the class are in the same namespace

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

First, I'm sorry for my poor English, I'm french.

When I use :

`php ./vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities ./model --generate-annotations=true`

I get this error :

**Fatal error: Class 'Repository\DefaultRepository' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\MyApplication\model\Repository\AnneeCultureRepository.php on line 5**

I installed Doctrine2 using Composer

The files structure is :

```
- library
--- intern
----- bootstrap.php
----- cli-config.php
- model
--- Entity
----- AnneeCulture.php
--- Repository
----- AnneeCultureRepository.php
----- DefaultRepository.php
- vendor
```

bootstrap.php :

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$paths = array("model");
$isDevMode = true;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'        => 'pdo_mysql',
    'dbname'        => 'MyApplicationDb',
    'user'          => 'root',
    'password'      => '',
    'host'          => 'localhost',
    'charset'       => 'utf8',
    'driverOptions' => array( 1002=>'SET NAMES utf8')
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

cli-config.php :

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

require_once 'bootstrap.php';

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

AnneeCultureRepository.php :

```
<?php

namespace Repository;

class AnneeCultureRepository extends DefaultRepository {

}
```

defaultRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder;

class DefaultRepository extends EntityRepository {

}
```

What am I doing wrong for getting this error?

Comment: Are you using Symfony ? Because if it is the case, that's not how you use the console tool (and even if you're not using Symfony, the principle should be the same : never use directly the vendor. It is used only by your framework, not by you.)

Comment: I'm not using Symfony. I use the vendor for doctrine and because the database evoluting with the project and need update with rapidly tools.
And because it's all i know :p

Comment: Any idea for resovled the problem?

Comment: i'm SO STUPID
with a require of my DefaultRepository class is so much better
problem solved